# Equivalent of "Dear Staff"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, correspondance

What is the equivalent of "Dear Staff" in an email?
For instance, a CEO wants to send an email to all the employees to invite them to a meeting. How could he or she start his email?

> Chers/chères collègues; Mesdames, Messieurs; Chers/chères employé.e.s; Chers/Chères collaborateurs/collaboratrices

Are any of these forms acceptables?

Comment: Ça me fait penser aux mails que le patron d'Apple envoie à ses salariés. Ça commence par "Team" et c'est signé "Tim".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones I would avoid:

> Mesdames, messieurs

for being too distant,

> Chers/chères employé.e.s

because inclusive spelling can be considered to carry a political agenda, and

> Cher collègues

because it implies the CEO is a peer the employees (already mentioned by beauchette).

I would probably agree with

> Chers collaborateurs, cher collaboratrices

although I would have avoided it a few decades ago.

I guess I'd just recommend to start that mail with :

> Bonjour à tous

or

> Bonjour à toutes et à tous

Answer (score 2):

All of these forms are acceptable and wouldn't make me raise an eyebrow, but :

- 'Employé' would feel a little weird, especially if some of them are in charge of others.
- 'Collègues' would be a little weird too because it conveys a thing of equality that you obviously don't have with your employees if you are their CEO.

So I'd go with 'Collaborateurs' because everyone is technically, a 'collaborateur'.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can use these forms as an equivalent of "Dear Staff":

- Chers/chères collègues
- Chers/chères associé.e.s
- Chers/chères collaborateurs/trices

These expressions give a kind of closeness between the CEO and his employees.

In contrast to the terms: employees or even workers.

Comment: Because it is still controversial, the inclusive spelling of *associé.e.s* (or better/worse *associé·e·s*) might not be acceptable depending on the company.